# Is there a theorem for this?

Tags: integers

Let say $a_0, a_1, ..., a_k$ are a series of positive integers, with $k > 0$, if one of the number has irrational square root, $\sqrt{a_n}$, such as $\sqrt{2}$, or $\sqrt{3}$, there is not way we can find a series of $a_0, ..., a_k$ to make 
$$\sqrt{a_0}+ \sqrt{a_1} + \sqrt{a_2}+ ... + \sqrt{a_k}$$ is an integer.

Is this assumption correct? Is there a theorem for this? Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure it is duplicate. I mean square root, not any b1, b2,,, bn.

Comment: Uh Oh, how can I edit with symbol square root? It seems someone helped me but got the last equation wrong. I tried to correct and now it messed up.

Comment: sure it's not an exact duplicate, but this is a special case of  that question.  I will fix your latex.

Comment: Thank you, @vadim123. I don't understand the other question.

Comment: Rational and Integer are not synonyms.  Integers are a subset of the rational numbers.  Regardless, that relaxation is easy to answer with a very quick yes.  Take for example $\pi + (6-\pi)$.  Both $\pi$ and $6-\pi$ are irrational and positive, yet $\pi+(6-\pi)=6$ is an integer.  Your original question is much harder.  As for interpreting the linked question for your case, your case is the special circumstance where all of $b_1,b_2,\dots,b_k$ are all equal to two and some of your summands are possibly rational as well.

Comment: Thank you, @JMoravitz. I see your points. So the answer is yes or no?

Comment: The answer is that the sum can never be an integer, unless each of the summands are integers too.  This is not a named theorem, as far as I know, but follows from some powerful machinery from a mathematical subject called field theory.